# How to duplicate an html file with a single number in each file incremented?

Tags: html, bash, terminal, grep, heredoc

I have a basic 10 line html file, but I need to duplicate the file 300 times. In the file there is a number that I need to increment by 1 so that the first file contains a "1" and the last file contains a "300."

For obvious reasons I don't want to type it manually.

The number refers to an image file.

HTML example of what will duplicate:

```
<img src="image_001">
```

Last HTML file example:

```
<img src="image_300">
```

Any ideas?

I assume I could do it in the terminal and use grep commands?

Not sure how though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash and a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {001..300}; do

cat << EOF > file_${i}.html
<img src="image_${i}">
EOF

done
```

or indent with tabs (no whitespaces) and `<<` replaced by `<<-`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {001..300}; do
        cat <<- EOF > file_${i}.html
                <img src="image_${i}">
        EOF
done
```